# Method works but throws errors for particular numbers

Tags: java, math

I wrote a method that calculates the combination of 2 numbers and it works for smaller numbers where n = 10 and r = 3, but when input n as 100 and r as 3 it throws an arithmetic exception
" / by zero"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Combination {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter n: ");
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\nEnter r: ");
        int r  = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        int ans = factorial(n) / (factorial((n-r)) * factorial(r));
        System.out.print("\nThe combination is: "+ans);
    }
    static int factorial(int num) {
        for(int i = num; i>1; --i) {
            num *= (i - 1);
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

but i don't know what the problem is. it works for smaller numbers of n.

Comment: I think it might be because the intermediary results are out of range of int type in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're multiplying values which result in a number too big to fit inside an integer.

If you print out the `num` inside your `for` loop, you'll notice it eventually either goes negative or to zero. This is due to overflow.

For your example of `n=100` and `r=3` not even `long` will do. You'll need to use something like `BigInteger`.

Keep in mind that using `BigInteger` will drastically slow down your program when compared to using primitives.

If you're not interested in having such large numbers and were just curious why it wasn't working, you can also use `Math.multiplyExact(int x, int y)` or `Math.multiplyExact(long x, long y)` if you're using `Java 8` or above.

By using these methods, you'll avoid having to deal with the side-effects of overflow since they will throw an `ArithmeticException` if the result overflows.

Comment: Thank you soo much. your solution worked

Answer (score -1):

Change the data type of num from int to double

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).